# Clamping Force required

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am currently working on a design for a beer pump (liquid dispenser) of (15 kg approx.), that will be clamped to a table with 2 clamps. This component has a handle attached to the top, where approximately 150 N will be applied each time the beer is to be poured. I need to determine how much clamping force is required for the component to stay rigid into the table without falling. I am new to this field, hoping someone can guide me towards the right answer.

Comment: Can you add a diagram?

Comment: For every force there is an equal and opposite reaction. So, you have worked out the force to be applied now consider how to counter that force plus any mass of the objects.

Comment: You need a lot more analysis than this if you want to engineer it, and you really need to understand the basics of forces and mechanics.  Forces need to be turned into vertical and horizontal components, plus moments (turning forces).  The length of the handle matters.  Unless you're building this for production and sale, most people would do this via looking at it and adding clamps that worked.  Not everything requires engineering.

Comment: If you add a photo or dimensioned diagrams it would be great.